# COPY from command not returning row count

Tags: postgresql, copy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbl1c.png)

I have two DB instances both running PG 12.6
I am trying to copy CSV data into tables.

Expected Output:

```
postgre_test=#\copy public.table_name from '/home/file.csv' with (format csv );
postgre_test=#COPY 5

Actual Output:
postgre_test=#\copy public.table_name from '/home/file.csv' with (format csv );
postgre_test=# (not thing)

\copy public.table_name from '/home/file.csv' with (format csv );
```

Comment: Step one would be to use a recent psql version, not 9.2 that is over a decade old

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, `psql` will ignore the `;`.

Comment: **DO NOT use images** for textual information. Copy and paste as text into your question. Then more people would have seen the error: `WARNING: psql major version 9.2, server major version 12. Some psql features might not work.`. Some features don't seem to be working. Use `psql` version that is from Postgres 12 or greater.

Comment: Thank you.
Cause psql version